# Scala typesafe-activator project timeout osx

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm playing a bit with scala and play framework, but when i try to run my test project  using activator, sbt on a mac i keep getting:

```
    [info] Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:39) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:321) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:113) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
[info]  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:127) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:125) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:323) ~[na:na]
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:43) ~[na:na]
```

I'm not really sure what am i doing wrong.

Comment: I guess more "context" is need to understand when exactly this error occurs? using `run`? after dependency resolution?

Comment: This issue appears in the same way as in my project. I am using Play Framework 2.4.3 and it happens when I run activator run

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I've found the solution here https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201821186-Namenode-fails-to-start-with-error-jurisdiction-policy-files-are-not-signed-by-a-trusted-signer-

I already had installed Java 8 JDK on my machine so I had to download the policy files from this website: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Then I just pasted the files to the location which is provided in the "readme.txt". 
The loction depends on the OS that you are using.

And everything works fine :)

Comment: How is your answer and provided links related to the question?